# Convergence in operator topology while having strictly smaller range

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Provide an example of a bounded linear map $A\colon X\to Y$ between Banach spaces for which there exists bounded linear maps $A_n\colon X\to Y$ with $\text{Ran } A_n=D$ a strict subset of $\text{Ran }A$, and $A_n\to A$ in the operator norm.

Here is a preliminary attempt: taking $X=Y=l^2$ and $(Ax)_j=\frac{1}{j}x_j$, observe that the sequence$\{A_n\}$ defined by $(A_nx)_j=(Ax)_j$ if $j\leq n$, $0$ otherwise, tends to $A$ in the strong operator topology and each $A_n$ has range strictly contained in the range of $A$. However, the range of each $A_n$ is not the same across $n$, so this doesn't quite work. I'm not sure how to fix this example, or if it can be fixed at all. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The set $D$ needs to be dense in $Ran(A)$. So $Ran(A_n)$ needs to be dense in $Ran(A)$ for all $n$.

Comment: @daw you can also show that $D$ cannot be closed in $Y$, but I'm not sure how that helps with producing an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected in your "preliminary attempt," the multiplication operator $A$ on $H := \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ given by $(\xi_j)_{j \geq 1} \mapsto (\frac{1}{j} \xi_j)_{j \geq 1}$ is indeed one example of such an operator $A$.

For $n \geq 1$ let $B_n$ denote the multiplication operator on $H$ determined by the sequence whose $j$th entry is $j$ when $j < n$ and $1$ otherwise.  Each operator $B_n$ is bounded and *invertible*, so the operators $A_n := A^2 B_n$ all have same range as the operator $A^2$.  [For the entirely optional purpose of understanding a motivation behind this construction, note that while the operator $A$ is not invertible in $\mathcal{B}(H)$, the sequence $B_n$ is trying as hard as it can to "approximate" "$A^{-1}$."]

For $n \geq 1$ the operator $A - A^2 B_n$ is also a multiplication operator, determined by the sequence whose $j$th entry is $0$ when $j < n$ and $\frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{j^2}$ otherwise.  Because this sequence is bounded above by $\frac{1}{n}$, it follows that that $\|A - A_n\| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ holds for all $n$, so that $A_n$ converges to $A$ in norm as $n \to \infty$.

It can be readily checked that the range of $A^2$, which is obviously a subspace of the range of $A$, is a *proper* subspace of the range of $A$, for example, because $(\frac{1}{j^2})_{j \geq 1}$ is in the range of $A$ although it is not in the range of $A^2$.  In near-tautological but perhaps more concrete terms, we have $\operatorname{ran}(A^2) = \{\xi \in H: (j^2 \xi_j)_{j \geq 1} \in H\}$, while $\operatorname{ran}(A) = \{\xi \in H: (j \xi_j)_{j \geq 1} \in H\}$.

In a similar spirit as the comments to the original post, note that no example can exist with $A$ invertible; if $A_n \to A$ in the operator norm and $A$ is invertible, the operators $A_n$ are eventually also invertible, and hence have the same range as $A$.

Note also that there are examples with invertible limits if one only requires that the limit exist in the strong operator topology.  As one example, with $B_n$ and $A$ defined as above, one can check that $A B_n$ converges strongly to the identity (note that $\|(I - A B_n) \xi\|^2 = \sum_{j \geq n} (1 - \frac{1}{j})^2 |\xi_j|^2 \leq \sum_{j \geq n} |\xi_j|^2$ holds for $\xi \in H$), although the common range of the operators $A B_n$ (i.e., the range of $A$) is not all of $H$, for example, because the sequence $(\frac{1}{j})_{j \geq 1}$ is in $H$ but is not in the range of $A$.